# Cannot find variable on client side react code

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, reactjs

After some research on the benefits of the isomorphic/universal javascript apps and server side rendering I have decided to use it in a project.

I am using Express.js and React.js to achieve server side and client side rendering.

One problem I have faced recently is my browser javascript cannot find a React variable which is a React component. It gives the error message of well known `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: QuestionBox`.

This react component is defined in the `questionbox.js` and this file used for server side after transpiled by `babel` in node.js and for client side rendering after `browserify`ed and `rectify`ed in a `gulp` task.

What can be the point here I am missing? It can be the gulp generated transformed file that is loaded by the browser by a script tag. [The full code is in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/isikfsc/b19ccb5e396fd57693d2f5b876ea20a0)

`questionbox.js`:

```
var React = require('react');
var marked = require('marked');
/*
    -QuestionBox
        -QuestionList
            -Question
*/
var Question = React.createClass({//Omitted here for simplicity: https://gist.github.com/isikfsc/b19ccb5e396fd57693d2f5b876ea20a0});

var QuestionList = React.createClass({//Omitted here for simplicity: https://gist.github.com/isikfsc/b19ccb5e396fd57693d2f5b876ea20a0});

var QuestionBox = React.createClass({
  loadQuestionsFromServer: function() {
      return true;
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.loadQuestionsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadQuestionsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="questionBox">
        <h1>Questions</h1>
        <QuestionList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports.QuestionBox = QuestionBox;
```

`gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var reactify = require('reactify');

var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

function scripts(watch) {
  var bundler, rebundle;
  bundler = browserify('src/components/questionbox.js', {
    basedir: __dirname, 
    debug: !production, 
    cache: {}, // required for watchify
    packageCache: {}, // required for watchify
    fullPaths: watch // required to be true only for watchify
  });
  if(watch) {
    bundler = watchify(bundler) 
  }

  bundler.transform(reactify);

  rebundle = function() {
    var stream = bundler.bundle();
    //stream.on('error', handleError('Browserify'));
    stream = stream.pipe(source('bundle.js'));
    return stream.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/components'));
  };

  bundler.on('update', rebundle);
  return rebundle();
}

gulp.task('watchScripts', function() {
  gulp.watch('./src/components/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return scripts(false);
});

gulp.task('watchScripts', function() {
  return scripts(true);
});
```

Comment: could it be the way you are exporting? aka `module.exports = QuestionBox;` instead of `module.exports.QuestionBox = QuestionBox;` might be worth trying

Comment: I am trying that right now.

Comment: I have tried it and now I have long error message saying: `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
   at invariant (/Users/isik/Dev/atelye/mt/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:38:15)
   at instantiateReactComponent (/Users/isik/Dev/atelye/mt/node_modules/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:66:134)
   at /Users/isik/Dev/atelye/mt/node_modules/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js:37:31
   at ReactServerRenderingTransaction.Mixin.perform... `...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the component is not (and really should not be) exposed to the global scope.

All the code inside the browserify bundle in not accessible from outside. So what should be done next is moving render function into the bundle.

To begin with, you can create new file (say, `entry.js`) and set it as an entry point for browserify in gulpfile.js:

```
bundler = browserify('src/entry.js', {
```

Then, You could move JavaScript from the template (.ejs) to this entry point.

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var QuestionBox = require('./components/questionbox.js').QuestionBox;

ReactDOM.render(QuestionBox({}), document.getElementById('mount-node'));
```

As long as browserify bundle is only used by the client, You don't have to change anything on the server.

Comment: You could check the [gist](https://gist.github.com/isikfsc/b19ccb5e396fd57693d2f5b876ea20a0)

Comment: yep youre right. you should beef up the answer by providing how to use it

Comment: @Роман, At the moment my `index.html` uses a `components/bundle.js`as the entry point built by the browserify and rectify inside the gulp task. However it does not have the last line you have given, that line is in the `index.html` since the same file is used in the server, too, and it, `ReactDOM`, does not make sense to the server. So, I have put it in the `index.html`.

Comment: @ışık All the changes you've made would not affect the server. I've updated the answer with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thanks @Роман, I get it. Server requires, in the `router.js`,  the React components from the file `questionbox.js`, so not the `ReactDOM` file, which is the `src/index.js` as the entry point for the browserify bundle to produce `dist/bundle.js`.

Comment: And as you say, `All the code inside the browserify bundle in not accessible from outside. So what should be done next is moving render function into the bundle.` That was the problem.

Comment: @Роман, I also think and need to send to the browser an `initialState` by the `props` just after server-side render. How is it possible in that above schema? I would insert the `initialState` in to the template file as I do the server side rendered React `<% markup %>` by putting it into a type `application/json` `script` tag. And then parsing it and making a `ReactDOM.render(Question(initialProps), mountNode)`.
Maybe I should go same way, insert initState into template, then grab, parse etc. this initState variable from inside later loaded bundle script just before `ReactDOM` and use in it.

Comment: I think that's a completely valid solution. Are you expiriencing any difficulties?

Comment: @Роман No not at all. I am now struggling with a completely different and may be more basic difficulty in reading the initialState from a script tag where I have server side rendered it. Seeing a `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"` when I try to parse it with `var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML)`.